# Would a "Hunting Horn" be feasible in a realistic world?

Tags: internal-consistency, music

Meet the "Hunting Horn" from Capcom's "Monster Hunter" franchise.

[image]

While the source video games undoubtedly take liberties, the idea of a large, handheld instrument that plays various tones by physically swinging the device does not seem *immediately* improbable. (A fair number of hunting horns from the games incorporate standard instruments such as bagpipes or guitars. For this question I'd like to focus on those archetypes that lack such secondary instrumentation)

Other aspects of the concept (such as use as a practical blunt weapon, or supernatural song-powered enhancements) are ancillary in my case; I'm primarily concerned with the feasibility of using physical movement to create tones, rather than traditional methods of sound creation such as blowing air, plucking strings, or percussion.

Are there any real world instruments that are played by moving the instrument?

If not, what considerations would factor into the shaping or utility of such a device? How might one form multiple tones from a single horn? (The games traditionally have precisely three each)

Comment: "played by moving the instrument" - specifically, tonal instruments utilizing airflow? because there's also instruments like [maracas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maraca) which require movement but don't utilize airflow nor generate tones.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Yes, tonal instruments utilizing airflow. That's a way better descriptor!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Corrugaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirly_tube)**

<sup>AKA whirly tube, bloogle resonator.</sup>

First seen in orchestras in the 1960s as an experimental musical instrument, a tube with internal ribbings, swung around through the air to make musical notes which "phased" depending what direction the tube pointed at any given time.

[image]

<sup>Hyacinth CC BY-SA 4 Wikipedia 2021</sup>

By [Bernoulli's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle), the air moves through the tube toward the circumference from the middle.

Like a bugle, the 2nd 3rd, 4th 5 the and 6th harmonics can be played, the faster the higher, maybe even further harmonics with considerable effort.

Structurally, the closer the ribbs, the higher the resonances will be, and the faster it's swung, the higher the pitch, but always in harmonic jumps, not continually.

It's described as hypnotic, mesmerizing to hear.

Comment: Known to fans of P.D.Q. Bach as the "Lasso D'Amore".  Not sure this would make a very effective *weapon* though.  I don't know if the OP was expecting it to work as both a weapon and an instrument or not?

Comment: Known to children as those ribbed stretchy straws you get in souvenir cups at amusement parks.

Comment: I'm seriously hoping they'd be a bit more rigid and threatening than day-glow plastic. @DarrelHoffman

Comment: Is the shape necessary for the instrument to function? Could you house it _inside_ a larger club-type object?

Comment: Sure you can, or ream-out a branch with a special tool to give it the internal ribs. An option might also be to have multiple hollow (ribbed) tubes bound together, each with a slightly different length at the weapon end, the end that goes through the air fastest - then have the horns, spikes etc. attached around those. The effect then would be to make a musical chord (major, minor or sour as per design for the individual warrior) - so the thing is personalized. @RavenDreamer

Comment: A practical demonstration using these tubes rotationally & percussively, done entirely live by [Walk Off The Earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LT7MOirwZdM) [YouTube video link] A band well-known for their unusual arrangements of existing songs.

Comment: ...'bloogle resonator'?

Comment: Couldn't it be made into a rigid flail-like weapon?

Comment: @Redbud201 I'm tempted to go and make one, just to prove a point, though I've no antlers 'n stuff to add to the end.

Comment: If you get some of those corrugated tubes used inside walls for electrical cables, they work great, although I have never managed to make more than one frequency on them.

Answer (score 30):

*Are there any real world instruments that are played by moving the instrument?*

**Yes,** the [bullroarer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullroarer). A traditional instrument throughout the world (Australian Aborigines, North American natives, and prehistoric Scandinavians all used them, as did the ancient Greeks), a bullroarer is basically a length of wood on a cord that is spun in a circle. Different pitches can be obtained by varying the radius of the circle, rotation speed, direction, or by twisting the cord so the body spins around its length.

[image: British Isle bullroarers]

Various examples from the British Isles showing different styles. I suspect different patterns of notches, grooves, and holes would also lead to different sounds. (Image from Wikipedia.)

You'll notice that they have some key differences from the hunting horn. First of course is their size - a typical bullroarer is about the size of your forearm, rather than a gigantic monster head on a stick. Second (and related), they are spun in a continuous circle rather than an arc - you need to move them relatively fast to generate any appreciable noise, and if they were only swung in an arc, the note would be very short.

So while there *are* instruments played by swinging them, they don't have much in common with the hunting horn.

Comment: The bullroarer is not an instrument - that is, you can't play different notes or rhythms with it.  It's simply a noismaker.

Comment: @jamesqf the same applies to [Vuvuzelas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuvuzela), yet they're considered instruments. Albeit the bullroarer allows change in pitch, which even the common vuvuzela doesn't.

Comment: @ Tim: From your link "Many types of vuvuzela, made by several manufacturers, may produce various intensity and frequency outputs."  Though calling it an instrument seems to stretch the definition unreasonably: you might as well say the cannons in Beethoven's "Wellington's Victory" are musical instruments :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Many percussion instruments don't play different distinct notes, [or even distinct pitches at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpitched_percussion_instrument), but no one would call a bass drum "not an instrument" (possibly for fear of upsetting the bass drummer).

Comment: @Cadence: Notice that I wrote "notes or rhythms", thinking specifically of drums & other percussion instruments.

Comment: "you might as well say the cannons in Beethoven's "Wellington's Victory" are musical instruments" in that context, they are percussion instruments.

Comment: @jamesqf Actually, with one constructed correctly, you _can_ play varying pitches. By putting a sliding collar on the string so you can adjust the length of string it’s spinning on, you can adjust the pitch smoothly kind of like a slide whistle or trombone. Actually doing any kind of musical performance is difficult though, and it would make a mediocre weapon.

Comment: @jamesqf "*The bullroarer is not an instrument - that is, you can't play different notes or rhythms with it*" is completely, utterly FALSE. Please research next time. Maybe start with this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ODGE2f7gLQ

Answer (score 9):

Apparently known by various names, in the west it appears to most commonly called a Chinese pigeon whistle

https://www.loc.gov/item/dcmflute.1188/
[image: DCM 1188: Anonymous, Chinese / Whistle ("Ko-ling" or "Shao-tzu")]

https://collections.mfa.org/objects/50624
https://www.akg-images.com/archive/Chinese-pigeon-whistle-2UMEBMBG32L7S.html

I first encountered these when attached to a replica Roman "Draco" standard to make a noise as the cavalry charged.

Comment: This is interesting! The noise it makes is tied to the bird's movement as they fly. Definitely seems like what we're considering!

Answer (score 8):

#### Battle Theremin

As a musical instrument, the [theremin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5qf9O6c20o) is played by not touching it, by moving one's hands through the electrical fields generated by the instrument and the player's body.

One could easily reverse the relative motions: place the theremin inside the weapon and make music while bashing a variety of monsters and evil hordes of EM generating Orcs and Blue Elves.

The key here will be the artful balance between interacting one's own body with the instrument and the bodies of one's foes.

Comment: I'm just imagining a little theramin dagger making high pitched squealing sounds as you get stabbed repeatedly by it.

Comment: @WolfieSmith -- The Squealing Dagger of Sqriim.

Comment: That is a new level of awesome for a two word combination

Answer (score 5):

The [pūrerehua (AKA: bullroarer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullroarer) dates back to at least 18,000 BCE and was common among many stone aged civilizations across the whole world.  It is basically nothing more than an airfoil at the end of a string. When swung around in the air, it makes a loud whirring noise. The faster you swing it, the higher pitch sound it makes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ODGE2f7gLQ

If you want a weapon that is an instrument when swung, you could perhaps reshape the blade of a [Kyoketsu-shoge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyoketsu-shoge) or other similar chain whip like weapon to make the same sort of noises.

Answer (score 5):

I note that MH's hunting horn is a club-like weapon so the responses mentioning the bullroarer are, while technically correct, somewhat beside the point.  So, to answer the question of the "feasibility of using physical movement to create tones" using a swung wind instrument, some casual searching shows:

- It takes about 0.5 - 1.0 psi of air pressure to operate a tuba, from a quick eyeball of fig. 3-4 of http://articles.ircam.fr/textes/Freour10b/index.pdf .  Other instruments require less though.
- We get a formula of psi = mph^2 / 56327.87 (from https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-psi-can-be-achieved-from-a-60mph-wind.698861/ ) resulting in an estimate of 167-237 mph velocity to generate the necessary 0.5 to 1.0 psi pressure over the horn intake.
- From https://www.beyondtheboxscore.com/2015/2/11/8010803/zepp-swing-sensor-perfect-game-100-mph-swing, we see that some of the best baseball players in existence can reach a swing speed of ~100mph, for a pressure at the end of the bat of about 0.18 psi.

Given that, the answer seems to be a definite "maybe".  0.18 psi is enough to operate some wind instruments and the MH hunting horn is longer than a baseball bat, meaning the tip could exceed 100mph if swung at the same angular rate, although it would require more strength to do so.

Comment: forget the tuba, which is just resonator that attaches to the lips, and doesnt itself produce noise. how much pressure does it take to operate a flute?

Comment: @Jasen  According to https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Mouth-pressure-versus-note-played-for-the-five-flutes-in-a-chromatic-scale-playing_fig4_233553982, most of the tonal range seems to be possible with less than 0.26 psi.

Answer (score 1):

While not *exactly* meeting the criteria of this question, I did once attend a folk-music performance where a very skilled concertina player was demonstrating a few things.

As part of this, he swung the concertina around in wide vertical circles while playing it, which led to some wierd "doppler" audio effects, especially since we were in a relatively small function room!

However, I'm guessing this was more due to the changing position of the concertina, rather than the effect of the changing angle of the air pressure.

Either way, it was definitely a fascinating audio experience!

Comment: Cool, what you describe sounds like a natural Leslie-concertina (Look up the Leslie speaker if you do not know it)

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the variation in tone had something to do with the doppler effect, assuming that the concertina was being consistently keyed throughout the motion.